# How to force initial navigation with SammyJS

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, sammy.js

I have a SammyJS-based single page application running under `http://[mydomain]/[myapp]/[subPath]`.  The server is configured to return the same HTML "startup" page no matter what `[subPath]` is, i.e. the route is configured with a wildcard for the subpath.

Since I want users to be able to bookmark a particular subpath in the application (e.g., "/orders/123"), I need to force the client to navigate to that subpath once the "startup" page is loaded.  What is the best way to do this?  I've tried doing `window.location.pathname = window.location.pathname` after setting up my application, but that just caused an infinite loop of re-navigating to the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating the SammyJS application, simply pass `window.location.pathname` to the `run()` method as follows:

```
Sammy(function () {
    this.get(/* custom route */, function (context) {
            // ... handle navigation ...
    });
}).run(window.location.pathname); // Voila!
```